# what is wrong with python my python code in while loop?

Tags: python

I don't know what is the error of my code can anyone help  me to fix this code.

```
age = ""
while int(len(age)) == 0:
    age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
print("Your age is " + age)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cast `age` to be an `int` inside of your while loop, while using the `len(age)` as the comparison.
`int` does not have a length.

You want to wait to cast `age` until you are outside of the loop, or in this situation, don't cast it at all.

```
age = ""
while len(age) == 0:
    age = input("Enter your age: ")
print("Your age is " + age)
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanted a string for age but you transformed this age into an integer inside your loop :)

You can write :

```py
age = ""
while age == "":
    age = input("Enter your age: ")
print("Your age is " + age)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `""` and `0` (and values like `None` and empty containers) are considered "falsey". Not necessarily the same thing as `False` but logically treated like `False`.

So you can simplify your `while` loop:

```py
age = ""
while not age:
    age = input("Enter your age: ")
print("Your age is " + age)
```